# Is there a simpler way than using a for loop for generating csv files regarding 4000 cities using R?

Tags: r

I am trying to generate a separate csv files for around 4000 cities using R. I wrote a small for loop for this.

All the cities data are stored in one single dataframe called cities_files.In the for loop I split this consolidate dataframes into a small temporary dataframe for each city and write this temporary data frame into a csv file .

```
cities.list <-  unique(cities_files$city_name)

for( cities.list  in cities_files$city_name )   {

tmp <- subset(cities_files,city_name == cities.list) 
cit.name <- unique(tmp$city_name)
fn = paste(paste(cit.name) ,".csv", sep = '')     
write.csv(tmp,fn ,row.names = FALSE)
}
```

However this for loop is taking around 3 hours to generate these 4000 files. Can i use something other than a for loop to get the desired results? Or is there a better way to optimise this code? I want to reduce the time taken to generate these files.

Comment: use `data.table::fwrite` instead of `write.csv`, it will vastly speed up the write time.

Comment: Should I replace only write.csv with the fwrite function or the entire for loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looping over every observation. You might want to consider a `data.table` approach.

**Update**
As @MichaelChirico pointed out, the `data.table::split` method should be used.

```
library(data.table)

cities_files <- data.frame(bar = c(1:20000), 
                        city_name  = rep(paste0("city ", 1:200), 100), 
                        foo = c(1:20000))


microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    khaynes = {
        # library(data.table)
        # Set the data.frame as a data.table
        cities_files_dt <- data.table(cities_files)
        lapply(unique(cities_files_dt[, city_name]), function(city) 
            fwrite(x = subset(cities_files_dt, city_name  == city), 
            file = paste0(city, ".csv")))

    },
    MichaelChirico = {
        cities_files_dt <- data.table(cities_files)
        list_dt <- split(cities_files_dt, cities_files_dt$city_name)
        for(i in 1:length(list_dt)) {
            fwrite(list_dt[[i]], paste0(names(list_dt[i]), ".csv"))
        }
    },
    times = 5
)
# Unit: milliseconds
#       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#    khaynes 661.0689 680.6768 698.2449 683.1407 719.8056 746.5323     5
#    MichaelChirico 452.0800 456.5777 499.2832 458.0174 517.4398 612.3011     5
```

---

Using the `data.table` package should vastly speed up the processing time:

```
library(data.table)

# Create a dummy data.frame
cities_files <- data.frame(bar = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3), 
                        city_name  = c("city a", "city a", "city b", "city c", "city c"), 
                        foo = c(20, 14, 40, 50, 60))

# Set the data.frame as a data.table
setDT(cities_files)

lapply(unique(cities_files[, city_name ]), function(city) 
    fwrite(x = subset(cities_files, city_name  == city), 
    file = paste0(city, ".csv")))
```

Comment: you should use data.table's split method, and this can be done in one or two lines

Comment: Wow! This Helped. I can see the files getting generated faster, already! Thanks! :)

Comment: @MichaelChirico.. How to do that? I was going through the data.table's documentation after reading your comment, but I can't find what you're referring to.

Comment: Good point @MichaelChirico! I <3 data.table. I'll update my answer.